# Removing "copy #"-text from layers in photoshop using applescript

Tags: sed, applescript, photoshop-cs3

I am able to replace the name of every layer of the current document, but when I pass it "where name ends with" it fails & the exception does not give any valuable feedback.

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS3"
tell current document
    set name of every layer where name ends with "copy*" to "replace_using_sed"
end tell
```

end tell

Can you spot the error or perhaps you know an alternative way about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `copy*` is causing the error. You can't use `*` as wildcard in AppleScript. Instead, use `... where name contains "copy" ...`.

Here's my working version of your script (tested with Photoshop CS5):

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS3"
    set layerList to name of every layer in current document where name contains "copy"
end tell

repeat with currentName in layerList
    set layerName to text 1 thru ((offset of "copy" in currentName) - 1) of currentName
    tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS3"
        set (the name of first layer in current document where name contains "copy") to layerName
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in CS3. The exception is still very vague, so theres no help there. But if your snippet works on CS5 you've probably helped a lot of people out there. Really annoying this one!

Comment: Scratch that! I´ve restarted the script-editor & photoshop. Now it works. Still need some tweaks to work with layer-sets, but this is a really good start. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix the whole script, but it's called a "whose" filter... so replace the word "where" with "whose". I'm not saying a whose filter works with photoshop, but you can try. If it doesn't work then you have to get all of the layers, loop through them with a repeat loop, and filter each name one-by-one.